# form_for creating 'item' which belongs_to 'contest' is blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I hope the title, a blend of code and English, is sufficiently clear.

I have found very little documentation about this situation in my web searches... It seems even the official rails API guide and doc doesn't cover a form_for with a model that belongs to another.

I'm new to RoR, and it's fun! I am working with relationships and trying to create the form to make a new 'item' on a 'contest'. The problem is it is coming out completely blank, no HTML rendered whatsoever inside the body tags where the form should be.

Here is my routes.rb

```
resources :contests do
  resources :items do
    resources :votes
  end
end
```

My item#new

```
def new
    @contest = Contest.find params[:contest_id]
    @item = Item.new
end
```

My new.html.erb

```
<%= render 'form', item: @item %>
```

And my form_for

```
<% form_for @item, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :notes %>
    <%= f.text_area :notes %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Also, here is the route display

```
contest_item_votes_path GET /contests/:contest_id/items/:item_id/votes(.:format)    
votes#index

POST    /contests/:contest_id/items/:item_id/votes(.:format)    
votes#create

new_contest_item_vote_path  GET /contests/:contest_id/items/:item_id/votes/new(.:format)    
votes#new

edit_contest_item_vote_path GET /contests/:contest_id/items/:item_id/votes/:id/edit(.:format)   
votes#edit

contest_item_vote_path  GET /contests/:contest_id/items/:item_id/votes/:id(.:format)    
votes#show

PATCH   /contests/:contest_id/items/:item_id/votes/:id(.:format)    
votes#update

PUT /contests/:contest_id/items/:item_id/votes/:id(.:format)    
votes#update

DELETE  /contests/:contest_id/items/:item_id/votes/:id(.:format)    
votes#destroy

contest_items_path  GET /contests/:contest_id/items(.:format)   
items#index

POST    /contests/:contest_id/items(.:format)   
items#create

new_contest_item_path   GET /contests/:contest_id/items/new(.:format)   
items#new

edit_contest_item_path  GET /contests/:contest_id/items/:id/edit(.:format)  
items#edit

contest_item_path   GET /contests/:contest_id/items/:id(.:format)   
items#show

PATCH   /contests/:contest_id/items/:id(.:format)   
items#update

PUT /contests/:contest_id/items/:id(.:format)   
items#update

DELETE  /contests/:contest_id/items/:id(.:format)   
items#destroy
```

Comment: did you paste the whole form? looks like you're missing a `<% end %>` at the end

Comment: Try replacing your `form_for` line with `<% form_for model: [@contest, @item] do |f| %>

Comment: I missed the end block here, it is present in the file though. @AmitPatel, if I replace it with the form_for you provided I get an undefined method 'model_name' on Hash, but if I replace it with <% form_with model: [@contest, @item] do |f| %> I do not get an error, but I still get a white screen.

Comment: I have found very little documentation about this situation in my web searches... It seems even the official rails API guide and doc doesn't cover a form_for with a model that belongs to another.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go! My form_for call is inside a non-output tag. Changing <% to <%= reveals the output!

It seems that sometimes the answers to my questions end up being tiny details that are easy to miss when the problem seems complex. A word to those who stumble through here: consider the basics before re-iterating the complexities.